# No boot has been detected or the disk has failed

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, hp

I have been trying to install linux (first Ubuntu, like 5 times and later Scientific linux) on my HP envy 700 to have a dual boot Windows 7 - Linux. Computer details:

HP ENVY 700-527C Desktop, Intel Core i5-4570 3.2GHz Quad-Core, 12GB DDR3, 1TB SATA, 802.11ac, Bluetooth, Win7

To do that I created a 100 GB partition using the windows disk manager utility. Then I rebooted the computer and installed scientific linux from the DVD (standard procedure) into the 100 GB partition. Installation went well, no errors or warnings, but when restarted to boot with the installed linux I got the "No boot has been detected or the disk has failed" message. The problem is that I get the same error when I try to boot Windows 7 :(

This means I can select Windows or Ubuntu from the boot menu (I have to go to the BIOS menu to do it, ESC and then F9 when starting computer) but none of them boots the OS and both give the same error "No boot has been detected or the disk has failed"

If I insert an Ubuntu DVD and use the try Ubuntu option I can access the hard drive and all partitions are there (Windows (system, recovery) and Ubuntu, including EFI partition).

At this point I decided to follow HP website support to try to solve the problem. Now I think it was a terrible idea. In one of the steps HP recommends to Restore Factory Settings. After that the EFI section of the Boot menu is empty, no Windows no Ubuntu :(((

I feel that the Scientific linux installation process messed up with the EFI system but I am not sure. I ran Boot-Repair from Ubuntu live-session (boot from Ubuntu live-CD and choose "Try Ubuntu") following instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair 
Paste from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25997376/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So you're not using Grub or Grub2 to boot? You're using BIOS settings?

Comment: I have a GPT hard drive and I am using UEFI booting system. Any help?

Comment: I think Scientific Linux did not install the Grub bootloader correctly for some reason. Screenshots of how you boot to each system might help.